# iOS Swift 3.0 Facebook login Blank screen | presenting view controller issue

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3

I have below view controller hierarchy in stack.

> Navigation Controller -> MainViewController -> LoginViewController

The code is working fine if i integrate it in MainViewController but not in LoginViewController
I tried to pass **window.rootViewController** but nothing.

```
let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logOut()
        fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = .systemAccount

        //Where self is LoginViewController
        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"], from: self, handler: { (result, error) in
            if((error) != nil){
                print("\(error?.localizedDescription ?? "no localized description found")")
            }else if(result?.isCancelled)!{
                print("cancelled")
            }else{
                print("Success")
            }
        })
```

Comment: any errors you get?

Comment: nothing, if i use window.rootViewController then i get already presenting sidemenu.